# Pandas Plot ax doesn't work when index is Timestamp

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, plot, timestamp

Running into an odd problem. I'm trying to plot a dual line graph time series, with the difference between those graphs shown as bars in the same graph.

```
ax = dfx['diff'].plot(kind='bar')
dfx['p1','p2'].plot(ax=ax,kind='line)
```

So far, so good, this works and gives me the visual I'd like but because the index is made up of unicode date strings, the x axis is a jumbled mess. So I go back and convert the index into timestamps:

```
dfx['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(dfx['Date']))
```

I then reset this new column as the index. Problem is, now when I try to plot it, the x axis is perfect, formatted nicely, but the "diff" bars completely disappear, yet it still shows up in the legend. Feels like whack-a-mole...one problem solved, another appears ;)

Thanks for your help!

Edit: After some testing, I've found that if I show the diff as a line, it's fine, which makes me think it's a problem with continuous vs discrete plotting. I think it's getting confused when attempting to show bar graphs on a continuous timestamp range...but I can't be the only person who's wanted to plot lines and bars on the same graph in pandas...

Comment: If you add a [MCVE] folks on here will be more likely to help :)

Comment: Can you add some data and incomplete plots?

Comment: Can you please check in how far [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813890/python-making-combined-bar-and-line-plot-with-secondary-y-axis)'s answers are solving your problem. And if they don't please specify, in how far your problem is different.