# Bar chart and plot with same ax

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a bar chart and a line from the same dataframe. I tried to use this simple code:

```
ax = df_h.plot(y='ActivePower',kind='bar',figsize=(16,8),linewidth=2, color=[colors])
df_h.plot(y='ActivePower',kind='line', ax=ax)
```

I followed some other [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482201/plot-pandas-dataframe-as-bar-and-line-on-the-same-one-chart) I am not sure what I am doing wrong but in the end I only have the last graph 'max plotted.

This question is not the same as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813890/python-making-combined-bar-and-line-plot-with-secondary-y-axis). I applied already the same suggestion there here and it does not work. I am still getting only one graph in the end, the last one. Therefore, the issue is different.

Comment: The code you show might or might not work, depending on the data in use. If you want to provide a [mcve], you may get help here.

Comment: please provide the minimal data,code so that this problem is reproducible. Thanks

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I provide the data frame that I am trying to plot

Comment: @user59271 I provide the dataframe that I am trying to use

Comment: You're missing a column, no?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have also tried with the same because I want bars and line but it did not worked it.